# Getting a price array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

In the current moment, I have a tensor `ytrue` with `ytrue.shape` equal to `(4650, 30, 161)`.

I am taking information every 5 seconds on the NYSE for a specific stock between 9:00 AM and 4:30 PM. So I have 4650 layers in the tensor which represent each 5 seconds during that period. Each layer has dimension (30, 161). 30 represents the number of steps I look in the past and 161 represents how many features (160 features + the price as the target).

I tried to reshape it the get the current price with

```
X = ytrue[:, :, -1]
```

but I got

```
ipdb> X                                                                                                                                     
array([[262.655, 262.605, 261.99 , ..., 263.615, 263.75 , 263.75 ],
       [262.605, 261.99 , 261.99 , ..., 263.75 , 263.75 , 263.71 ],
       [261.99 , 261.99 , 262.015, ..., 263.75 , 263.71 , 263.63 ],
       ...,
       [253.065, 253.03 , 252.93 , ..., 253.115, 253.18 , 253.27 ],
       [253.03 , 252.93 , 253.1  , ..., 253.18 , 253.27 , 253.345],
       [252.93 , 253.1  , 253.145, ..., 253.27 , 253.345, 253.35 ]])
```

I need to take the last element of each subarray to create an array of prices, e.g.

```
[262.655, 262.605, 261.99 , ..., 263.615, 263.75 , 263.75 ] --> 263.75
```

How can I get an array of each of those elements from `ytrue`?

Comment: `ytrue[:, -1, -1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fancy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/user/basics.indexing.html).

`X[:, -1]` should do the trick.

A smaller example you can easily eyeball:

```
In [4]: x = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)

In [5]: x
Out[5]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

In [6]: x[:, -1]
Out[6]: array([ 4,  9, 14, 19, 24])
```

HTH.

Comment: I think `X[:, -1]` should still work. I've got to run, but I'll check back later...

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. `X` is already equal to `ytrue[:, :, -1]`.  So I guess X has to be equal to `ytrue[:, :, -1] [:, -1]`?

Comment: Yes, that works. You could also just do it in two steps with `X` as a temp. Alternatively I believe `ytrue[:, -1,-1]` will work if you want it all on one slice.